# Array Value Output more than one

Tags: java, arrays, loops, conditional-statements, linear-search

This is the code I have come up with. However, I wanted to be able to output either:

- (value) is in slot x.
- (value) is in slot x.

*two outputs if the (value) is available in two slots -like 7.*

or

- (num) is not in the array.

**But not both.** 
Can anyone help please?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int search, counter;
    int num[]={3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 7,  9, 13};

    System.out.print("Array: ");
    for (int count=0; count<num.length; count++)
        System.out.print(+num[count] + " ");

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("\nValue to find: ");
    search = in.nextInt();

    for (counter = 0; counter < num.length; counter++ ){
        if (num[counter] == search)
        {
            System.out.println(search + " is in slot " + (counter + 1) + ".");
        }           
    }
    if (counter == num.length)
        {
            System.out.println(search + " is not in the array.");
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I feel like you should probably ask such a question on another community such as https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ I can offer a suggestion:

Use a boolean flag to check whether you have found it before. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int search;
  boolean found = false;
  int num[]={3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 7,  9, 13};

  System.out.print("Array: ");
  for (int count=0; count<num.length; count++)
      System.out.print(+num[count] + " ");

  Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.print("\nValue to find: ");
  search = in.nextInt();

  for (int counter = 0; counter < num.length; counter++ ) {
      if (num[counter] == search)
      {
        System.out.println(search + " is in slot " + (counter + 1) + ".");
        found = true;
      }           
  }

  if (!found) {
        System.out.println(search + " is not in the array.");
  }

  in.close();

}
```

So you only print the "not found" message when you cannot find the element after a linear traversal through the array...

Comment: suppose using a Boolean flag is the most suitable work around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you check if the counter has reached the arrays length. Something that will always happen. You should check if you found a value.

This should do the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int search, counter;
    int num[]={3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 7,  9, 13};
    boolean wasFound = false;

    System.out.print("Array: ");
    for (int count=0; count<num.length; count++)
        System.out.print(+num[count] + " ");

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("\nValue to find: ");
    search = in.nextInt();

    for (counter = 0; counter < num.length; counter++ ){
        if (num[counter] == search)
        {
            System.out.println(search + " is in slot " + (counter + 1) + ".");
            wasFound = true;
        }
    }
    if (!wasFound)
    {
        System.out.println(search + " is not in the array.");
    }
}
```